# deleting object in mongodb using nodejs causing error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

Hello am trying to delete object in my mongodb using nodejs. Here is my code :

```
module.exports.deletetopic = function (req, res) {
//var id = JSON.parse(req.body)._id;
var idd = req.query.id;
console.log('iddd dans serveur ' + idd);
Topic.findById(idd, function(err, topic) {
  if (err) throw err;


//console.log(topic.title);

  topic.delete(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('Topic successfully deleted!');
  });

});
}
```

But i get the following error :`topic.delete is not a function`

And here is how i call it on my client side :

```
$scope.deletetopic = function (id) {
  console.log('id est de ' + id);
  $http.delete('/api/deletetopic', {params:{id:id}});
  }
```

Can you help

Comment: It should be topic.remove not topic.delete.

Comment: @shubhamsaini it worked thanks why dont you answer the question and i will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **db.collection.remove()** to remove documents from a collection in MongoDb.

```
topic.remove(function(err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('Topic successfully deleted!');
});
```

Also as suggested you should follow these practices as well.

```
Topic.findById({id: idd}, function(err, topic) {
...
...
if(topic){
   // your query
}
else{
   console.log('some message');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove document by using `ModelName.remove({_id:receivedId})`

```
Topic.remove({_id:idd}).exec(function (err,doc) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).send('Error while deleting');
  }
  if(doc.result.n != 0){
    return res.status(200).send('Deleted');
  }
  return res.status(400).send('Not found');
});
```